# How to plot 'adjusting for a value' in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a large citizen science dataset that I am working with. I would like to find out the number of observations of the species adjusted for effort (Effort means the number of observations recorded in that year or month), essentially capturing the underlying trend.

```
The original dataset 'Species_df':
structure(list(scientific_name = c("Sciurus carolinensis", "Aglais io", 
"Pieris napi", "Pieris napi", "Polyommatus icarus", "Pyronia tithonus", 
"Argynnis paphia", "Amanita muscaria", "Ramalina farinacea", 
"Parmelia sulcata", "Hofmannophila pseudospretella", "Emmelina monodactyla", 
"Branta hutchinsii taverneri", "Grus grus", "Phalaropus lobatus", 
"Anser albifrons", "Turdus iliacus", "Aythya collaris", "Turdus merula", 
"Harmonia axyridis"), common_name = c("Eastern Gray Squirrel", 
"European Peacock Butterfly", "Green-veined White", "Green-veined White", 
"Common Blue", "Gatekeeper", "Silver-washed Fritillary", "Fly Agaric", 
"Farinose Cartilage Lichen", "shield lichen", "Brown House Moth", 
"Morning-glory Plume Moth", "Taverner's Cackling Goose", "Common Crane", 
"Red-necked Phalarope", "Greater White-fronted Goose", "Redwing", 
"Ring-necked Duck", "Eurasian Blackbird", "Asian Lady Beetle"
), taxon_name = c("Mammalia", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", 
"Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Fungi", "Fungi", "Fungi", "Insecta", 
"Insecta", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Insecta"), year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010), month = c(10, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 
1, 12, 9, 3, 2, 2, 9, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

  Effort_final <- species_df %>%
  select(taxon_name, scientific_name, year, month) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(total_effort = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(month_effort = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(scientific_name, year, month) %>%
  mutate(n_obs = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(year, month)
```

This is the modified dataset 'Effort_final':

```
    structure(list(taxon_name = c("Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", 
"Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Aves", "Insecta", "Plantae", "Plantae", 
"Plantae", "Aves", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta", 
"Insecta", "Insecta", "Insecta"), scientific_name = c("Branta hutchinsii taverneri", 
"Turdus iliacus", "Aythya collaris", "Anser albifrons", "Larus fuscus", 
"Larus fuscus", "Branta leucopsis", "Larus fuscus", "Aglais io", 
"Helianthemum × sulphureum", "Helianthemum apenninum", "Helianthemum nummularium", 
"Larus argentatus", "Melolontha melolontha", "Harmonia axyridis", 
"Chrysops caecutiens", "Aglais io", "Pieris napi", "Pieris napi", 
"Polyommatus icarus"), year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), month = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8), total_effort = c(35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), month_effort = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 11L
), n_obs = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), adj_effort = c(0.0285714285714286, 
0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0857142857142857, 
0.0857142857142857, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0857142857142857, 0.0285714285714286, 
0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 
0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 
0.0571428571428571, 0.0571428571428571, 0.0285714285714286), 
    adj_monthly = c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.181818181818182, 
    0.181818181818182, 0.0909090909090909)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which results in the: [following dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUVvw.png).

This is a large dataset so plotting it results in some serious over-plotting. I would like to avoid that. The current plot results[image: in something like this.]

The code I tried to plot:

```
ggplot(data = Effort_final, aes(x=year, y=adj_effort) + geom_jitter()
```

[This is the original species_df dataset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mt4V.png)

Comment: Please don't paste data as pictures. We can't do anything with it without retyping it (wasted effort), we can't see what data formats are used, and it doesn't work with screen readers. I suggest you run `dput(head(species_df, 20))` and paste the output into the body of your question. This will produce a code "recipe" we can run to immediately load up a perfect copy of the first 20 rows of your data in the same formats you have it.

Comment: Hi! Please add the code you used to generate your plot, as it is a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve.  So, if possible, also add a brief description of your desired output.

Comment: @JonSpring, I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: @JuanBosco : Yes I have added that in the question. It is basically a geom_jitter() plot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want specifically, but here's a variation using `count(x)` as a shortcut for `group_by(x) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% ungroup()`.

For overplotting, you might use `geom_jitter` (maybe with smaller `size` or `alpha` below 1) to get a better sense of the data frequency, or a summary layer like `geom_smooth` here, but alternatively could be boxplots, or density bins, or a monthly average...

I suspect your definition of effort will tend to make high numbers in years with few species observed. e.g. If we saw one crane in year 1 but 10 cranes and 10 ducks in year 2, your measure might go from 100% in year 1 to 50% in year 2.

```
Species_df %>%
  add_count(year, name = "year_ttl") %>%
  add_count(year, month, name = "yearmo_ttl") %>%
  add_count(year, month, scientific_name, name = "yearmospec_ttl") %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(paste(year, month, 1))) %>%

  # this says "what share of the month's obs were this species"
  mutate(effort_mo = yearmospec_ttl / yearmo_ttl) %>%

  # this says "what share of year obs were of this species this month"
  mutate(effort_mo_yr = yearmospec_ttl / year_ttl) %>%

  ggplot(aes(date, effort_mo)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_smooth(SE = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: You are exactly right about the effort decreasing over time because even though the number of observations of a particular species may increase with time but so do the overall observations recorded in that year. I was looking for a graph which accounts for adjusted_effort (n_obs/total_year) in a graph of Year ~ n_obs. Would there be any way to account for that?

Comment: Ok, then I think you want `ggplot(aes(date, effort_mo_yr)) +...` ?

Comment: Erm - I don't quite know. Is there anyway to adjust the number of observations (n_obs) according to the effort made (effort_made_yr)? And then plot it against date?

Comment: Sure, maybe you could map one to the `y` axis and one to the `scale` aesthetic, eg. `aes(date, effort_mo_yr, size = yearmospec_ttl)`.  What do you want to show?

Comment: I am looking to show something like, alright: Sure the effort (which is just the number of observations by year) increased and the n_obs (Recordings for a particular species) also increased with time, but can the increase tell us about the underlying trends observed in those particular species? That is my question.

Comment: Unless you have something specific in mind that you can articulate, this isn't really a programming question. It sounds like you should try some combinations of mapping time, n_obs, overall n_obs, and share to different aesthetics like `x`, `y`, `color`, `size`, facet, etc. I won't know which one you want.